# facebook share button og:url error

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to add some "share" buttons to a webpage I'm working on.  I keep getting an "og:url" and "og:title" error even though they're both there.  Any help would be great.  Below is the beginning of the webpage script.  Thanks, Marc

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>fccf pad promotion</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="FCCF Pad home"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://padsrockref.1sourceusa.com/fccfpad/" />
<meta property="og:description"
      content="A great way to start the new year!  Request some pads and One-Source will make a donation on your behalf to the FCCF."/>
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 from the url you have in `og:url` above

Comment: You should check your URL for typos etc. After pasting your go:url into facebooks debugger, it always lands on a 404 page... https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpadsrockref.1sourceusa.com%2Ffccfpad%2F

Answer (score 1):

When I go to the URL you specify (http://padsrockref.1sourceusa.com/fccfpad/) for og:url, I get a 302 redirect to another page (http://padsrockref.1sourceusa.com/PageNotFound.html).  So there are no og meta tags for Facebook to process, hence why it is erroring out.  Update it to a valid URL and I think that will solve your problem.